# How to get the transport rods back into a Hisense washing machine?

Tags: washing-machine, transportation

I have a Hisense washing machine and can not get the two transport rods back in [manual p. 14 direct download link](https://hisense.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/UM_HWGE9014.pdf). With a bit of twisting and turning I get them inside until about 5cm stick out. They need to go further in so I can attach the angular fixators. Any tricks?

Comment: They should go in the same way as they came out.  It says to turn 90 degrees, so they probably need to go in at 3 or 9 o'clock and turn(or something similar).  Finding the right position is the hard part.

Comment: @crip659 I slowly turned them 360 degrees while also pulling back and pushing forward to no avail :/

Comment: The problem is there is probably some flopping around before the hole.  Might also need to raise/lower, or move side to to side to hit the hole/opening.  Just remember that tossing it out a window only helps for a few seconds.

Comment: @crip659 What confuses me is that I can get them 90% and that already takes some fiddling. But after that it's just stuck and I'm hitting some metal part. If I pull it a bit back it and turn it, I can push the drum with it.